# Scenario of two or multiple users working on same content

Tags: sensenet

I'm working on SN community edition; I need to setup a like shared folder where two or multiple users can work on it.

I tried the following:

- Login with built-in user account "admin";
- Create a folder under "\Root" with name "SharedFolder";
- Modify the permission on this folder by giving built-in user account "mike" full permission.

The problem is that I couldn't see this shared folder in the dashboard of the users (admin, mike).

Comment: Is it a custom dashboard that you've created or is this the built-in 'My page' of the users that can be reached from the user's dropdown menu?

Comment: It is the built-in 'My page' ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in mypage's document library by default lists the childrens of /Root/Profiles/username/Document_Library.

The easiest way to achieve this is if you add a new List portlet to the 'My page' and bind it to the 'shared' folder. But this way you cannot list multiple shared folders in one list.

Steps to achieve this:

1. Copy /Root/Profiles/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse into to the chosen user profiles (/Root/Profiles/username/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse. This way the users that should work on the shared folder would have a custom 'My page' with the shared folder as a list
2. Navigate to the newly created Browse pages and switch to edit mode
3. Add a 'List' portlet to one of the zones
4. Open the portlet actions (top-right corner of the portlet) and click on 'Edit' to open the portlet property dialog.
5. There're tons of things on this dialog to set, but the three that you have to set is the ViewFrame on the 'Content List' tab (set is to: /Root/System/SystemPlugins/ListView/ViewFrame.ascx) and the Bind Target + Custom root path on the Contenxt binding tab (Bind target should be Custom root and add your shared folders path into the Custom root path)

The steps above should be made on all the userprofiles that are related. Another solution could be if you change the built-in profile Browse page (/Root/Profiles/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse). This way the shared folder will be displayed on every users 'My page' but the users who aren't allow to see the items of the shared folder will see an empty list.

To get all the 'shared' document/folder/content items you have to use the [permission queries](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Permission_queries#Methods) but they are only available through the OData or c# API, so you have to create a custom grid/collection view to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the steps to do mentioned easy way:

I am trying to do the steps as in following 

http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_add_a_portlet_to_a_page

Comment: "Another solution could be if you change the built-in profile Browse page (/Root/Profiles/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse). This way the shared folder will be displayed on every users 'My page' but the users who aren't allow to see the items of the shared folder will see an empty list." ------------->

I logged in into sensenet using 'admin' user account then I followed the above steps. I successfully bind a List portlet to the shared folder. but I could not see the portlet in the 'My page' of 'mike' user account although I update the permission of the shared folder. Please help @Aniko Litvanyi

Comment: Is there a Browse page in the (apps) folder of mike's user profile (/Root/Profiles/BuiltIn/mike/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse or /Root/Profiles/BuiltIn/mike/(apps)/This/Browse)?

Comment: There is no Browse page in the mentioned path!

Comment: The page (/Root/Profiles/(apps)/UserProfile/Browse) is edited by the admin user and maybe the changes was not checked in/published, so another users cannot see them. Login with admin, and check if the Browse page is not published. The needed information is displayed on the Portal Remote Control.