# Can not create a content hierarchy inside a shared folder

Tags: sensenet

I followed the steps in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509416/scenario-of-two-or-multiple-users-working-on-same-content) successfully, but I cannot make a new text document inside the shared folder.

I can create a top level folders inside the the shared folder, but I cannot also browse the folder to create second level folders and so on!

[image]

--

[image]

**Update 1**

Screenshot of Folder's Browse page

[image]

**Update 2** 
Screenshot of Folder's Copy of Browse page

[image]

**Update 3**

If we browse a folder from mike's My page ,like the one in below, we got a result as in the second screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the Folder content type has a separate custom Browse page and it is not the same as the one for the 'My page' which is a UserProfile. So if you want to make it work for folders:

1. Create a System Folder with the name (apps) into your 'shared folder' and a Folder in to the newly created (apps) folder with the name Folder
2. Copy the Browse page from the UserProfile folder (/Root/Profiles/(apps)/UserProfile) into the 'shared folder's (apps)/Folder folder
3. Change the list portlet on the Folder Browse page to display always the current folder (set CurrentContent as Bind Target and remove the path from the Custom Root Path input)

Check [this](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Smart_Application_Model) article about sensenet smart application model which is strongly related to your question.

Comment: I couldn't find the list portlet on the Folder Browse page! I update the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, copying the mentioned Browse page is a must. I updated my answer. Please try it again with copying first the UserProfile's Browse page into the /Root/Profiles/(apps)/Folder folder

Comment: Yet It doesn't work!  I update the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: I can not get it? Did you try to browse a folder from the my page? Can you attach a screenshot, how a Folder look if you browse it from mike's My page?

Comment: Update the question .. It looks like the second screenshot in the original question!

Comment: Did you publish/check-in the Browse page?

Comment: Yes it is checked-in!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160709/discussion-between-anas-tina-and-aniko-litvanyi).